# Prove R is an equivalence relation on A. Then Prove a partition is the set of equivalence classes of R

Tags: equivalence-relations, set-partition

P is a partition of a set A. Define a relation R on A by declaring $xRy$ iff $x,y\in X$ for some $X\in P$. Prove R is an equivalence relation on A, then prove that P is a set of equivalence classes of R.

I don't know how to prove this

Comment: What is the definition of an equivalence relation? What is the definition of an partition?

Comment: Equivalence relation is a symmetric, reflexive and transitive. Partition is a subset of a set s.t. the intersect with another partition is an empty set.

Comment: I don't know if you can prove R is a equivalence on A. Cause R only pertains to elements in X which are in P. For A to be symmetric then all the elements need to have a relation to itself. So if xRy for all X in P then we know all in X are symmetric, but we don't know that about those not in P.

Comment: Your definition of partition is wrong. It's a subset of the powerset of $X$ such that $\bigsqcup P=X$,

Comment: " Partition is a subset of a set s.t. the intersect with another partition is an empty set. "  Not quite.  A partition is a *collection* of subsets $X_\alpha$ so that *every* $a \in A$ is in precisely on $X_\alpha$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definitions of partition and equivalence classes are very closely related.

The definition of a partition is a collection of disjoint subsets $X_\alpha$ of $A$ so that each and every $a\in A$ is in precisely one $X_\alpha$.

So why does that imply an equivalence relation and why are the equivalence classes *precisely* the sets $X_\alpha$?

Why Reflexivity:  $a R a$ for all $a\in A$.  That is precisely the condition that every $a\in A$ is in some subset $X_a$.  There *is* an $X_a$ so that $a \in X_a$. So $a \in X_a$ and $a \in X_a$ so $a R a$.

Why Symmetry:  If $a R b$ then $b R a$.  Well, that's impossible not to be true!  If $a,b$ are both in the same subset $X_i$ then... they are both in the same subset $X_i$.  So $a R b$ means there is an $X_i$ so that $a,b \in X_i$ and so $b,a\in X_i$ and $b R a$.

Why trasitivity:  If $a R b$ and $b R c$ then $a R c$.  Why?  Well, this is where the $X_{\alpha}$ are *distinct* comes into play.  $a$ must by is some $X_a$.  But $X_a$ is the *only* $X_a$ so that $a \in X_a$ because that is what a partition is; each element of $A$ is in precisely *one* set.  So if $a R b$ then they are in the same set which means $b \in X_a$.  And that's the only set $b$ is in.  And if $b R c$ then $b$ and $c$ are in the same set.  And that set is $X_a$ because that's the only set $b$ is in.  So $a,b$ and $c$ are all in $X_a$.  So $a,c \in X_a$.  Which meas $a R c$.

No an equivalence class is collections of subsets $E_a$ of $A$ so that for each $a\in A$ then $E_a = \{b \in A|a R b\}$.  In other words $E_a = \{b\in A| a,b \in $ the same subset partion$\}$.  But there is only one partion $X_a$ that contains $a$ and $E_a$ is the set that has precisely all the elements that also in the same partition and nothing else; the $E_a$ is the set that contains all the same elements of $X_a$.  Which means $E_a$ is *equal* to $X_a$.  And that is true for every element and for every subset of the partition.  So $\{E_a\}$ is the exact same subset as the partition.